# Database version for jdeveloper 12.1.3

Tags: database, oracle, weblogic, jdeveloper

i need the oracle database version that compatible with Jdeveloper 12.1.3 please, because i try to configure the RCU, but show me error about database version, thank you very much>

Comment: check the version of the jdbc driver, that will give you all the info you need, or consult the docs http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121300-cert-2164864.html#Databases

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You can find the JDev compatibility matrix [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/121300-cert-2164864.html)

Comment: thank you, but i can't understand this document? i don't know what id the required database version? show me the database version directly if you can